# Stack from a program

Tags: stack

Given the following program, draw the stack, including all the elements (local variables, parameters, static link, dynamic link) of each activation record after Q is called in the body of C.

Program: -

```
Program Bar;
Procedure Top;
   var z: integer;
   Procedure A(x: integer);
 begin
  writeln(x+z);
   end;
   Procedure B(y: integer);
  Procedure C(Procedure Q(z:integer))
  begin
  Q(y);
  end;
```

begin
 C(A);
 end
     begin 
     z := 7;
     B(6);
     end
begin 
Top;
end

I dont know how to do this.

Comment: [What exactly do you not understand about the stack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981391/how-exactly-does-the-stack-work)

Comment: I do not know where to start. It says after Q,.. also I don't knoww the format.